# Notebook shuts off after exactly 30 minutes uptime

Tags: laptop, bios, shutdown

Recently i started using a old Notebook from Fujitsu. The Lifebook A512. I like it a lot, but it shuts down exactly after 30 minutes of uptime. This Problem is OS Independent. It is happening on Windows, Linux and even if i wait 30 Minutes in the BIOS configuration it just shuts off. I flashed the newest BIOS from 1.20 to 1.21, sadly no effect. I did a CMOS Reset and changed the CMOS-Battery two times. In the BIOS Configuration i tried every possible setting with no success. In every other aspect the notebook works perfectly, except for a borken card reader. I currently have Arch Linux installed, but as i sad the problem is not OS specific.
Im hoping for someone that has more experience in situations like this than me and i appreciate any help regarding this issue.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Is this notebook an Intel-based notebook and manufactured since 2008 or so?

If so, it contains the Intel Management engine (ME), which even if not exposed or enabled in the BIOS is present.  The ME provides many features useful in an enterprise environment, such as remote control regardless of any installed OS (the ME has its own independently running OS and network stack) for remote repair, and things like Intel Anti-Theft.

If the ME cannot load for some reason, the system will shut down in 30 minutes.  Reasons why the ME would not be able to load is if someone tried to remove it from the BIOS, or a BIOS update failed.

You may try reapplying the latest BIOS update to see if it will resolve the issue.

Comment: I see. But sadly i already reapplyed the latest BIOS update cause i thought it may be corrupted. But after the update it still shuts down after 30 minutes.

Comment: I always flashed the BIOS Updates via FreeDOS. Successfully. Ill try it now in a regular windows env... I dont think it will work, but its worth a try.

Comment: Only other thing I can think of is maybe see if one of the earlier BIOS updates flashes the ME part of the BIOS.  I know from updating Dell BIOSes that some of them have an ME update and others don't.  Then flash the latest version.  During Dell BIOS updates it says "Sending ME Update" during the portion where it updates the ME.

Comment: There is a "Initial BIOS" Version at the Fujitsu Support Page. Ill try it out. Thanks.

Comment: Not your fault. But the BIOS is now corrupted and bricked. So yeah...

Comment: well heck ... :( I'm sorry.  It doesn't have any recovery mode where it will immediately flash from an external USB or similar?

Comment: Yeah i already looked for a recovery jumper. But without any luck.